# Compare selected option with last in list in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

In a HTML drop down select of years, I want to compare the selected option with the last option in the list. Like this:

```
  $('#YRNext').click(function() {
    if ( $('#year option:selected').val() != $('#year').last().val() ) {
      console.log($('#year').last().val())
      console.log($('#year option:selected').val())
      $('#year option:selected').next('option').prop('selected', 'selected');
      $('#year').trigger('change');
    };
  });
```

However, the if statement does not work. I always get the console message with the same year. 
What do I do wrong?

NOTE: I also tried:

```
if ( ! $('#year option:selected').is( $('#year').last() ) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#year').last()` is basically `$('#year')`, [`last()`](https://api.jquery.com/last/) takes the last entry in the jQuery set, and `$('#year')` only has one entry.

To get the last option in that list, you could use `$('#year option').last()`:

```
if ( $('#year option:selected').val() != $('#year option').last().val() ) {
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^
```

Another option (as it were) is to use `selectedIndex` on the underlying `HTMLSelectElement`:

```
var year = $("#year")[0];
if (year.selectedIndex === year.options.length - 1) {
```

That's *slightly* different if you have options that have the same value, but typically you don't, in which case it would do the same thing.

Comment: Ahhh.... Yes, thank you. That I should have seen.
(I'll use the first solution)